# Is there a way to execute function before unloading razor view of _Layout asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I know that I can bind handler to `onbeforeunload` event and execute something before full page unload. But is there a way to do this on razor view of _Layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,it could,If you add the js codes in _layout,when you leave the page,it would work
I added the codes  in my layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function (){
            return("");
        }
    </script>
```

when I leave the page, a dialogue pop out
[image]

You could share your codes if you have problems when you add the function of onbeforeunload